# How can I tell whether an element matches a selector?

Tags: javascript, dom

Let's say I've got a DOM element - how can I tell whether it matches a jQuery selector, such as `p` or `.myclass`? It's easy to use the selector to match children of the element, but I want a true/false answer to whether this particular element match?

The element may not have an ID (and I can't assign it a random one for reasons beyond this), so I can't apply my selector to the element's parent and look for children with the same ID as mine.

Will this work as intended? I can't figure out Javascript object comparisons.

```
$(selector, myElement.parentNode).each({
  if (this == myElement) // Found it
});
```

Seems like there would be an easy way to see whether a DOM element matches a jQuery selector...

Comment: duplicate of - https://stackoverflow.com/q/3304638/104380

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Test if a selector matches a given element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304638/test-if-a-selector-matches-a-given-element)

Answer (score 37):

You can use the [`is()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Is) method:

```
if($(this).is("p")){
 // ...
}
```

Comment: but does this work like this? `$(this).is("body .content p")` -I would need something like this

Comment: It seems it should do that just fine.

Answer (score 5):

## Without jQuery, using [Element.matches()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/matches):

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('div');

console.log(
   elements[0].matches('.foo'),         // true
   elements[0].matches('.bar'),         // false
   elements[1].matches('[title=bar]'),  // true
)
```

```html
<div class='foo'></div>
<div title='bar'></div>
```

---

[See supported browsers list](https://caniuse.com/#feat=matchesselector)

Answer (score 2):

I believe the [is()](http://docs.jquery.com/Is) method is what you are looking for.

Otherwise, you might just try selecting the item directly, if that is what you mean.

So if it's an "a" with a class of "myclass", just do  $("a.myclass")

Answer (score 1):

> I can't apply my selector to the
>   element's parent and look for children
>   with the same ID as mine.

You can't do that anyway - the `id` attribute must be unique.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you just want:

```
$(".complicated #selector p.with > div.manyParts").length
```

If there are no matches, length returns 0, which is falsy, so you can use it in an `if` statement, like:

```
if($(".doesThis #exist").length) {
    // Do things
}
```

Probably would be worth storing it in a separate variable and THEN checking the length; that way, if you need to do anything with the matched elements, you don't have to execute the same selector again.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Element.matches()`

[Element.matches()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches)

```
document.addEventListener("click", event => {
  if (event.target.matches(".elementsClass")) {
    // It matches
  } else {
    // Does not match
  }
});
```