document.write(htmlPage) throwing SCRIPT1002: Syntax Error in IE but works in Chrome and other browsers
I have an Iframe that loads up an HTML page. The HTML page contains the usual html code along with some javascript with it. When I do a document.write(HtmlData); then in the F12-IE chooser app I see a Script 1002 Syntax error but the whole transaction proceeds without any errors. I have tried replacing the document.write() method with srccode, src, innerHTML, outerHTML but the closest I have got to things working was using InnerHTML which does not fully load the HTML contents of the page and does not throw that SCRIPT 1002 error. There is no way for me to step inside(debugger) the document.write() to see which exact line it's throwing the error.
Console only this shows up:
SCRIPT1002: Syntax error
application (13,4)

which points to this reference in the HTML index page
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/json-viewer.css" />
The goal is to not have SCRIPT 1002: Syntax Error show up at all.
Code for the function that contains the error
Client side the error that I saw on the console was 
SCRIPT 257: Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101
JqueryCode.js(line,column)
Exact code on that line: 
(window.execScript || function(data){
   window["eval"].call(window, data);
})(data);

/**
 * This function makes the iframe and sets it up so the terminal
 * can be accessed through it
 * @param {String} data The html that is passed through as a string 
 * @param {String} rootURL The URL that we are replacing the old one with
 */
function initIframe(data, rootURL) {
  if (data == undefined || rootURL == undefined) {
    return;
  }
  console.log(data);
  var regex = /(<head>)/g;
  var baseURL = "$1\n\t\t<base href=\"" + rootURL + "/\" /><!--[if IE]></base><![endif]-->";
  var updatedData = data.replace(regex, baseURL);
  var iframe = document.getElementById("vtIFrame");
  iframe = iframe.contentWindow ? iframe.contentWindow : iframe.contentDocument.document ?          iframe.contentDocument.document : iframe.contentDocument;

  try {
    console.log("Initiating process to load terminal Iframe.");
    iframe.document.open();
  } catch (e) {
    log("IFrame was blocked by browser.", "error");
    log("Check console for more information.", "error");
    console.log(e);
    console.log("For correct perfomance, please use Google Chrome with start parameters: --args --user-data-dir=\"/tmp/chrome_dev_test\" --disable-web-security ");
  }
  console.log("Vt page loaded on to Iframe.");
  iframe.document.write(updatedData);
  iframe.document.close();
}


Tried:
I have tried replaceing document.write() with InnerHTML which does not throw the error but couldn't get to load contents to the Iframe successfully. I have tried including src and srccode in an inframe as well.I have tried the babel transpiler as well and pretty much transpiled every javascript code that I have to see if anything works. I have tried adding the content as a BLOB which does not go well with IE.
Tried Debugging through each and every one of the variables to see if any exceptions are caught anywhere or if any meaningful errors are caught.
Some errors which may or may not be unrelated as part of the debugging variables are as follows:
"Error: Unspecified error.\n   at initIframe (url/resources/javascript/globals.js:1076:3)\n   
above is the line which corresponds to document.write(); 

 the following parth points to a line in the Jquery library somewhere

at c (url/resources/jquery-min-3.3.1.js:1091:44)\n   

at f.fireWith (url/resources/jquery-min-3.3.1.js:1128:21)\n    

at l (url/resources/jquery-min-3.3.1.js:2932:413)\n    

at Anonymous function (url/resources/jquery-min-3.3.1.js:3023:235)" 


Basically made some progress with this error. To give context, IE basically throws SCRIPT1002: Syntax Error and the line points to a CSS reference in the header section of the page, and I used the Chrome debugger to see if I could find something that IE was not showing and around the same line of code I saw the debugger pause on the following exception DOMException: Failed to execute 'webkitMatchesSelector' on 'Element': '[test!='']:sizzle' is not a valid selector. .

Looked at [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24510726/dom-exception-while-using-minified-js] , but not finding anything related to the code that I can change or fix as the above exception gets thrown from the Jquery-1.7.2-min.js file.
