# Is element a descendant of some class?

Tags: javascript

```
<div class="blah">
  <div id="hi">Hi</div>
  <div id="hi2">
    <p id="hi3">Hi3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**How to test with JavaScript if an element is child (or grandchild, or grandgrandchild, etc.) of an element of class `blah`?** (said in another way : if an element is contained in an element of class `blah`).

*Note: After some tests, `.contains(...)` seems not to be the solution.*

Comment: by jquery traversing

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_traversing_ancestors.asp

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_traversing_descendants.asp

Comment: @kki3908050 how would you code a `function isContainedByClass(src,cls)` with these jQuery traversing ancestors methods? can you give a small example?

Comment: i have created code below please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through parents, check each one.

```
function isContainedByClass(src,cls) {
    while(src && src.tagName) {
        if( src.classList.contains(cls)) return true;
        // apply old-browser compatibility as needed

        src = src.parentNode;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You probably should make clear in your answer that the source element itself is taken into account (just like with jQuery's [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method), so you cannot match an ancestor if the class you pass is also exposed by the source element.

Comment: @Leo, I hope you're not serious :) *(What if `src` is `null` to begin with?)*

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Yep, like I said, bad smell. Just showing off how to make it "awesome" :D

Comment: @Leo, ah. Then I would personally go with `for (src = src && src.parentNode; src; src = src.parentNode) {}` instead. That's even less readable, of course.

Comment: I guess nobody ever bothered to test this. If no match is found, it will progress up to the document element, which has no `classList`, and result in a JS error.

Comment: @torazaburo Corrected, your Highness.

Comment: It seems to be 100% working : http://jsfiddle.net/wm5mopgw/ . Why the downvotes ?

Comment: Seems to work perfectly, can you give an example of case for which it doesn't work @FrédéricHamidi ?

Comment: I've reversed my downvote, but the original solution had two problems. Running off the top of the DOM when there is no match has now been addressed. The second has not; as another commenter pointed out, the solution still does not actually match the spec, which says "child (or grandchild, or grandgrandchild, etc.) of an element of class", not "descendant or **self**".

Comment: My bad, I forgot to mention that testing if self has the required class is fine (even required!)... But yes, descendant would be a problem: does the current code returns `true` if a descendant contains a an element of class `cls` ? (I don't think so, but not sure)

Answer (score 2):

Use `matches`:

```
elt.matches('.blah *')
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.matches. Check browser compatibility.

See also [Test if a selector matches a given element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304638/test-if-a-selector-matches-a-given-element/16579057#16579057).

Modernizr can help if the browser you are targeting requires a prefix:

```
var ms = Modernizr.prefixed("matchesSelector", HTMLElement.prototype, elt)
ms('.blah *')
```

See http://modernizr.com/docs/#prefixeddom.

Comment: A bit ham-fisted, but functional.

Comment: Using standard calls but much more expensive : `-1 != [].indexOf.call (document.querySelectorAll ('.blah *'), elt)`

Comment: @HBP Yes, that is approximately what the polyfill given on the MDN page does.

Comment: It seems to be not available with `matches` on many browsers, but rather with prefix `moz-matches` : http://caniuse.com/#feat=matchesselector ... This is annoying to have to deal with this...

Comment: @Basj Have added note about using Modernizr to address that problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
**check this out**
============================================================================

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.a *
{ 
display: block;
border: 2px solid lightgrey;
color: lightgrey;
padding: 5px;
margin: 15px;
}
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 //for checking if span with class c1 is  children of class a element
   if($('.a').children('span.c1').length > 0) {
        console.log("Found");
     }

//for checking if span with class c1 has  parent element with class a    
     if($('.c1').parents('.a').length > 0) {
        console.log("Found");
     }
  });


</script>
</head>
<body>


<div class="a">a
        <div class="b">b
            <div class="b1">b1</div>
            <div class="b2">b2</div>
            <span class="b3">b3</span>
        </div>

        <div class="c">c</div>
        <span class="c1">c1</span>
        <p class="c2">c2</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```