# how to check a javascript DOMElement against a selector query

Tags: javascript, dom

I've got a DOM element in a variable, like

```
<div>
    <div id="hello"></div>
</div>
...
var a = document.getElementById("hello");
```

then I need to know if `a` would be caught by this selector query

```
"div>div.stuff"
```

**How do I check if a stored DOMElement fullfills a selector query?**

Answer (score 4):

You can check if the element `.matches` the passed selector string:

```js
var a = document.getElementById("hello");
console.log(a.matches("div>div.stuff"));
```

```html
<div>
    <div id="hello"></div>
</div>
```

```js
var a = document.getElementById("hello");
console.log(a.matches("div>div.stuff"));
```

```html
<div>
    <div id="hello" class="stuff foobar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should post an answer here as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304638/test-if-a-selector-matches-a-given-element :)