# How can I check if the querySelector of a clicked element is correct using if statement?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, queryselector

first post here.
I was trying to make some tests using the if statement to fire an `Alert`, for example, when there's a lot of whatsApp buttons on website, but with difference in specifications on it.
So i tried to run this code:

```js
window.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    if(event.target.querySelector('a[href*="whatsapp.com"]')){
        console.log('Hey WhatsApp!')
    }
})
```

But this code isn't works, it does not return an error on Console, but it does not fires the `console.log`

You guys knows what is wrong with this code or if there's a way to validate on the `if` statement the `querySelector` of a clicked button?

Comment: Please add a [mcve] (-> add the relevant markup for 1 or 2 of those "buttons") preferable as [runnable snippet `<>`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Comment: Most probably the node referred by `event.target` does not have any children matching your querySelector. You can try with `event.target.parentNode`

Comment: Try [Element.matches](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304638/test-if-a-selector-matches-a-given-element

Answer (score 1):

I think, you misunderstanding what `querySelector` is used for. This method returns first child element, whose selector is matched with that you passed as an argument.

Maybe, you don't want to `addEventListener` to the `window` object and then catch all propagated click events. Instead of that, try to find your whatsApp button via `document.querySelector` and `addEventListener` directly to it. Something like:

```
const whatsApp = document.querySelector('a[href*="whatsapp.com"]')
whatsApp.addEventListener('click', ev => {
  console.log('Hey WhatsApp!')
})
```

[querySelector documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)