# Check if given selector matches given object

Tags: jquery, selector, match

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I tell whether an element matches a selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596150/how-can-i-tell-whether-an-element-matches-a-selector)

I've been using jQuery for this javascript framework I've been working on and I was wondering if there is a way of checking if a given selector matches a given jQuery object. Something like:

```
var divObj = $(document.createElement('div'));
var result = divObj.hasSelector('div');
```

Result would either return a "true" or the object back if the selector matches the object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can tell if an object is a div using:

```
$('selector').is('div');
```

Or for a direct comparison:

```
$('selector1')[0].tagName == $('selector2')[0].tagName
```

Comment: This compares just the *first* element (if it exists) of each set, `.is()` will match if any of the elements in the set matches the selector (which also might be much more complex).

Comment: I was just simplifying the code by using a selector. I was assuming that there would be exactly one element selected.

Comment: @T.J. - wait, what? When was `.get()` deprecated?

Comment: @Crowder answer modified

Comment: @Nick: My bad, it **isn't** deprecated. I could have sworn, but [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/get/) say otherwise and in fact mention that there are advanced features of `get` (like, say, negative indexes) which the bracket notation doesn't support.

Comment: @Marcus: Sorry about that, and I've deleted my comment because it looks like it's misleading and incorrect. But in the simple case of a zero or positive index, I'd avoid the function call anyway.

Comment: @T.J. no problem, brackets are syntactically neater anyway.

Comment: Separate note on that second check (whether via `get` or `[]`): It assumes that there *will* be at least one matching element for both selectors, and will throw an exception if there isn't.

Comment: Yes, however these problems are all selection considerations, and are not relevant to the question which apparently already has a reference to a specific object or object.s

Answer (score 2):

There's a [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) function *exactly*  for this:

```
var divObj = $(document.createElement('div')); 
var result = divObj.is('div');
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/ZBKya/).  Note that this is a simple case, be aware in other situations [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) returns `true` if *any* of the elements in your jQuery object you're running it on matches the selector.

Comment: If you want to be sure to just check the *first* one (rather than seeing if *any* of the matched elements match), you can always do `$(divObj[0]).is('div')`.

Comment: @TJC: In that particular case *I'd* rather not trouble jQuery and just go with `divObj[0].tagName == "DIV"` :-)