# How to combine "this" with another selector?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to write a selector, that gets `this` object only in case it is an anchor. I want it to get nothing in case it is anything but `<a>` tag.

```
$('.link').mouseover(function(){

    $("a", this).css('color','#00F');

})
```

the `$("a", this).css('color','#00F');` doesnt work, but has desired effect if i leave only `this` in query. all the other selectors i could find in examples, blogs, and documentation were for getting children objects ( `find()` `children()`), combining two selectors(with `add()`), or pretty much anything else but the thing I'm looking for. can anyone help, please?

Comment: Your selector would be exactly the same as `$(this).find('a');` or in other words it tries to find all elements matching the description given on the left within the context of the element referenced on the right.

Comment: Can you post some HTML mark-up that clearly identifies what you're trying to select? Currently I'm wondering why you don't just use `$('.link a')` as your selector, which clearly means I'm missing, or misunderstanding, something.

Comment: @David Thomas: `a.link`, indeed, it would make more sense

Comment: .find( selector ) Returns: jQuery

Description: Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element. - from jquery documentation. -- i need the same object, not the descendants. it does not work

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I tell whether an element matches a selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596150/how-can-i-tell-whether-an-element-matches-a-selector)

Comment: In which case use `a.link` (as @zerkms suggested). What problem are you having?

Comment: Did you try using a filter like Matt suggests, sounds like that is what you are really looking for, and not find().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either use the `is()` method to check whether `$(this).is('a')`, and then react accordingly;

```
if ($(this).is('a')) {
    $(this).css('color', '#00F');
}
```

But perhaps a better solution in this situation is to use the [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter) method to `$(this).filter('a').css('color','#00F');`

To note, `filter()` filters the *current* jQuery object; so `$('*').filter('a')` would filter the `a`s out of allll the elements. `$('a', this)` on the other hand (equivalent to `$(this).find('a')`) searches descendants of elements in the jQuery object which match the provided selector.